# SELECT COUNT(*) in a Left Join

Tags: mysql, count, left-join, rows

So, I have a simple left join:

```
SELECT 
      a.SetNumber, 
      a.SetID, 
      COUNT(a.QuantityOwned) AS Pwnd,
      b.ImageURL, 
      COUNT(a.Quantity) AS Cmplt
FROM a
LEFT JOIN b ON a.SetNumber = b.Number
GROUP BY a.SetID
```

That produces this:

```
SetNumber 11 21 13

SetID 1 2 1

Pwnd 45 33 50

Cmplt 50 36 50

ImgURL a.jpg b.jpg c.jpg
```

Which is fine, when I use the data, but I want a >> arrow in my pagination and to do that I would like to get the amount of rows, ie the desired result in this case is:

```
3
```

I know I can count rows with `COUNT(*)` in one table, but how do I do it in a left join?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you need to do that

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM (SELECT a.SetNumber, a.SetID, COUNT(a.QuantityOwned) AS Pwnd ,b.ImageURL, COUNT(a.Quantity) AS Cmplt
    FROM a
    LEFT JOIN b ON a.SetNumber = b.Number
    GROUP BY a.SetID) table1
```

The `left join` is'nt the problem here, it's the `group by`

But a lot of "Libraries" Allows to count the result count like

```
$result->count();
```

In my opinion if you use JAVA, php etc... you don't need to do another request